# Struts 2 Eclipse Class Not Found error

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, xml-configuration

Configuring Struts 2 with Eclipse.  I am having a hard time getting this to work properly.  To my understanding, it can find the file, but it can't load the configuration file out of it.  What am I doing wrong? I've cleaned the program, all the maven dependencies appear to be there.  I have another working project and honestly everything looks spot on the same, except that one works, and this one doesn't.

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/devl/workspaces/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/sunday/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:70
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5508)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Action class [com.manifestcorp.sunday.SundayAction] not found - action - file:/C:/devl/workspaces/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/sunday/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:70
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:482)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:552)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:258)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Your action class isn't being deployed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `FilterDispatcher` in the new project, this one has been deprecated long time ago. The current struts2 filter class could be configured in the [`web.xml`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html) as

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.manifestcorp.sunday</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note, the init parameter allows you to specify packages to scan for action classes.